# Fstab doesn't mount with exec

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, executable

I have an ext4 partition that I mount using the following fstab line

```
UUID=41dec246-654d-4e35-9d4e-68150e40c5b0 /mnt/Data     ext4    defaults,user      0      2
```

But then I realized that I can't execute from that partition. I checked my mount options and they were: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev

So I changed the mount options to be more explicit as follows:

```
UUID=41dec246-654d-4e35-9d4e-68150e40c5b0 /mnt/Data     ext4    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async      0      2
```

But the partition still mounts with the same options (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using UEFI booting. I'm also dual-booting with Windows 8.1

Comment: user implies noexec and order count so `auto,user,exec` if you need dev or suid or rw add them

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change that line to

```
UUID=41dec246-654d-4e35-9d4e-68150e40c5b0 /mnt/Data     ext4    rw,suid,dev,auto,user,async,exec      0      2
```

The position of `exec` is important, since `user` also applies `noexec`.  By putting `exec` after `user`, you ensure that `exec` is set.  The most important options should be listed *last*.

Comment: This was the key to solve my problem. I had exec first and all my problems went away after moving it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back from 22.04.
This works for my laptop using Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS) and SSD with following commandline.

`UUID=4B55B50364DA6FC6 /Data ntfs-3g defaults,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0777,fmask=0111,umask=0022 0 0`

This works for me with the correct dmask and fmask.