# Cannot run .sh file in fstab Mounted vfat partition

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, fstab

So, I'm dual booting and I've created a shared partition to use between my two OSs. This is formatted as fat.

For access via my Ubuntu 18.04.2 OS, my fstab entry to automatically mount this partition is as follows:

`UUID=<PARTITION_UUID> /mnt/storage vfat rw,exec,auto,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000 0 2`

On boot, the partition is available and all user, group and permissions look in line according to the fstab entry.

However when I run a .sh file, I get the error:
`bash: ./my_script.sh: Permission denied`

Running `ls -l` on my_script.sh I get:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 wildgooze wildgooze 76 Jun 10 21:37 my_script.sh`

Running the script fails with `sudo`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I had bumped into this before with NTFS partitions and what you set in the fstab file is correct, but I had to also change the mount folder to be owned by my user account and the same group as my account.

Comment: @EliahKagan I've updated the question as requested.

Comment: @Terrance I've unmounted the partition with `sudo umount /mnt/storage` and running `ls -l /mnt` gives me `drwxrwxrwx 2 wildgooze wildgooze 4096 Jun  4 21:38 storage` so I think my permissions on the mount folder look correct?

Comment: When it is mounted what does the storage folder show for its owner and group?

Comment: @Terrance When mounted the permissions show the same apart from last change is epoc: `drwxrwxrwx 8 wildgooze wildgooze 32K Jan  1  1970 storage`. I have tried creating a basic `echo hello` script and that still runs with the same permissions error.

Comment: Yeah, that looks right to me.  Is there a reason that you went with FAT32 over NTFS for the shared?  Mine are all NTFS that are shared and they have the permissions set the same and I can launch scripts without issue.

Comment: @Terrance I think I may have misread somewhere that there would be a greater overhead (re. compatibility) with ntfs?? Perhaps that maybe a old issue for older versions of Ubuntu. I've not got much on the share yet so may just reformat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging, I finally found the answer. Looks like the ordering of the options matter. I moved `user` before `exec` and I am now able to run scripts in the mounted partition.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678857/fstab-doesnt-mount-with-exec) is the one which helped.

Maybe this needs to be mentioned in the [Ubuntu Community Fstab page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)??

Comment: +1  I actually missed the order and really didn't know that either.  Mine are all configured just like `UUID="240433A6043379BE" /media/250GB_SHARE ntfs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`